# Positive integer solutions to the equation $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}=\frac{1}{143}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help to calculate the solutions of
$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}=\frac{1}{143}.$

Thank you, and I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I don't see any similar questions.

Comment: $n=m=143 \times 2$.

Answer (score 5):

Multiply $143mn$ on both sides.
$$143m+143n=mn \implies (m-143)(n-143)=143^2=11^2 \cdot 13^2$$
Thus, our solutions would be:
$$\{m-143,n-143\}=\{1,20449\},\{11,1859\},\{13,1573\},\{121,169\},\{143,143\},\{169,121\},\{1573,13\},\{1859,11\},\{20449,1\}$$
This can be seen by expressing $143^2$ as products of two integers. Now, you can solve for $m,n$.

Comment: I think you mean expressing $143^2$ as the product of two integers.  What about {121, 169}?

Comment: Just in case, $\{m,n\}=\{144,20592\},\{154,2002\},\{156,1716\},\{264,312\},\{286,286\},\{312,264\},\{1716,156\},\{2002,154\},\{20592,144\}$

Comment: $\{m, n\}$ could also be $\{264,312\}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are right. I have made the edits.

Answer (score 1):

You have $143(m+n)=mn$. Let $d={\rm gcd}(m,n)$ with $m=dm_1$ and $n=dn_1$; where $(m_1,n_1)=1$. You get $143(m_1+n_1)=dm_1n_1$. From here, you have, by observing $(m_1,m_1+n_1)=(n_1,m_1+n_1)=1$, $m_1n_1 \mid 143$. Recalling $143=11\cdot 13$, the possibilities for the pair $(m_1,n_1)$ are $(1,11),(1,143),(1,13),(11,13)$ (and its permutations/$\pm$ versions). The remaining is a finite casework, that I leave you as an exercise.

Comment: Dear, a question. If a and b are coprimes, then (a+b,a) = 1, I see u used these in your answer. It's ever true?

Comment: Richard, here it is. Suppose, $p$ is a prime number, that divides $(a,a+b)$. Then, $p\mid a$, and also, $p\mid (a+b)-a=b$, hence, $p\mid (a,b)=1$, which shows $(a,a+b)=1$.